# How to use an Azure certificate for IdentityServer4

Tags: azure, certificate, identityserver4

Created App Service Managed Certificates in Azure (TLS/SSL settings of the web service).
How can I use this healthy private key certificate in combination with the IdentityServer4? Something like?

```
"IdentityServer": {
"Clients": {
  "MyApp": {
    "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
  }
},
"Key": {
  "Type": "Store",
  "StoreName": "My",
  "StoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
  "Name": "?"
}
```

},

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to supply a (self-signed) certificate, see [How to configure key settings for IdentityServer in appsettings.json for aspnet core app running on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246219/how-to-configure-key-settings-for-identityserver-in-appsettings-json-for-aspnet) for further instructions. For creating a self-signed certificate see for example [make certificate with PowerShell](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell%20create%20self-signed%20certificate&rlz=1C1CHBD_enNL755NL756&oq=powershell%20createself-signed%20certificate&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.6257j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_wPWfXoHRL8LlkwX_povgDA42)