# .Net Core Accessing a Cert from the Local Computer store

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate

I have a .Net Core application whose cert expired which is currently being hosted directly on IIS. We changed the cert on the server, before I was accessing the cert on C drive but we've since installed it on the local machine in the cert store.

[image: Image of certificated stored on local computer]

I'm trying to access the Wildcard certificate in the store through the appsettings.json. However I'm still running into a `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure`.

From the windows logs I'm seeing:

```
'Invalid certificate store location 'Personal'
```

Currently I have this:

```json
   "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "Dashboard": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      },
    },
    "Key": {
        "Type": "Store",
        "StoreName": "LocalComputer",
        "StoreLocation": "Personal",
        "Name": "CN=Wildcard"
    }
```

Am I accessing the certificate the right way? Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Are you hosting this app in IIS? Or directly exposing Kestrel?

Comment: @mason I'm hosting directly on IIS.

Comment: Is the error in the Windows Event Log? Normally these sorts of errors show up there as Warnings.

Comment: @mason "Invalid certificate store location 'Personal'" from the windows logs.

Comment: Please edit that info into your question, including the full exception message and stack trace.

Comment: [Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246219/how-to-configure-key-settings-for-identityserver-in-appsettings-json-for-aspnet) show a store name of "My" and a store location of "CurrentUser". Did you look into that?

Comment: Have you tried setting it like this: `"StoreLocation" : "LocalMachine" , "StoreName" : "My"`?

Comment: @Chen yes, when I did that it worked however it won't pick up my cert. It finds the localhost one just fine which is what we're using for now.